# Custom Lightning Page error only in FireFox .The Notification permission may only be requested from inside a short running

Tags: visualforce, lightning-web-components, visual, firefox

I have a fully developed and tested Custom Lightning Page which has a VF component and Several LWC components. Everything was done in Chrome and working fine.  It is failing with the error message : "The Notification permission may only be requested from inside a short running user-generated event handler." in FireFox. ( I'm on latest v 88). I have no idea what is causing it and how to trace. This is the result of my research. My FF configuration browser.navigation.requireUserInteraction is false by default.  The other config dom.webnotifications.requireuserinteraction is true by default. If I change it to false I can overcome this issue for myself. But that is not an option to suggest to end users. ( There was bug related to this in FF which is closed now : [FFBUg](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1593644) I'm using all standard ways and approaches in my components on page, no crazy stuff. Please advise what may be causing this from Lightning side?